# Where do filters/kernels for a convolutional network come from?

Tags: neural-network, convolution, feature-extraction, deep-learning

I've seen some tutorial examples, like [UFLDL](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/ConvolutionalNeuralNetwork/) covolutional net, where they use features obtained by unsupervised learning, or [some others](https://timdettmers.wordpress.com/2015/03/26/convolution-deep-learning/), where kernels are engineered by hand (using Sobel and Gabor detectors, different sharpness/blur settings etc). Strangely, I can't find a general guideline on how one should choose a good kernel for something more than a toy network. For example, considering a deep network with many convolutional-pooling layers, are the same kernels used at each layer, or does each layer have its own kernel subset? If so, where do *these*, deeper layer's filters come from - should I learn them using some unsupervised learning algorithm on data passed through the first convolution-and-pooling layer pair?

I understand that this question doesn't have a singular answer, I'd be happy to just the the general approach (some review article would be fantastic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current state of the art suggest to learn all the convolutional layers from the data using backpropagation ([ref](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html)).

Also, [this paper](http://ftp.cs.nyu.edu/~fergus/papers/zeilerECCV2014.pdf) recommend small kernels (3x3) and pooling (2x2). You should train different filters for each layer.

Answer (score 1):

Kernels in deep networks are mostly trained all at the same time in a supervised way (known inputs and outputs of network) using Backpropagation (computes gradients) and some version of Stochastic Gradient Descent (optimization algorithm).

Kernels in different layers are usually independent. They can have different sizes and their numbers can differ as well. How to design a network is an open question and it depends on your data and the problem itself.

If you want to work with your own dataset, you should start with an existing pre-trained network [[Caffe Model Zoo]](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Model-Zoo) and fine-tune it on your dataset. This way, the architecture of the network would be fixed, as you would have to respect the architecture of the original network. The networks you can donwload are trained on very large problems which makes them able to generalize well to other classification/regression problems. If your dataset is at least partly similar to the original dataset, the fine-tuned networks should work very well.

Good place to get more information is [Caffe @ CVPR2015 tutorial](http://tutorial.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/).